# Cannot access the value of a StringBuilder in a heap dump in VisualVM

Tags: java, heap-memory, visualvm, heap-dump, oql

I am willing to write the value of a large `StringBuilder` with index `827` to disk. I am trying to do that using the following OQL:

```
map(heap.objects('java.lang.StringBuilder'),
 function(it, index) {
  if (index == 827.0) {
      var writer = new java.io.FileWriter("/Users/username/output/sb_0x" + it.id.toString(16) + ".txt");
      var chars = it.value;
      for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
          writer.write(chars[i]);
      }
      writer.close();
  }
  return index;
})
```

However, nothing gets written. I now that the builder exists, since I have inspected it:

[All StringBuilder objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC0P3.png)

It seems that the result gets truncated after the builder with index `99` (i.e. it works for 99, but doesn't work for 100):

[Truncated after 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoINK.png)

Any suggestions how can I get the value of the StringBuilder with id 827?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query:

```
filter(heap.objects('java.lang.StringBuilder'),
 function(it, index) {
  if (index == 827.0) {
      var writer = new java.io.FileWriter("/Users/username/output/sb_0x" + it.id.toString(16) + ".txt");
      var chars = it.value;
      for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
          writer.write(chars[i]);
      }
      writer.close();
      return true;
  }
  return false;
})
```

Comment: It would be even more helpful if you explained what the difference is between the original code, and why it makes a difference.